# How do I change the legend position in a NVD3 chart?

Tags: charts, d3.js, legend, nvd3.js

Does anyone know how to reposition the legend in a NVD3 chart relative to the graph itself?

It is on top by default, and I would like it to go on the side (better use of space within my app)

An example of what I would like to do:
[image]

Answer (score 14):

As of this writing (2 jul 2015) **nvd3** supports putting the legend to the right of the pie chart.

When you initialize the graph, set `legendPosition` to `right`.

Example:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })          
      .legendPosition("right");


    svg.datum(piedata).call(chart);

  return chart;
});
```

See http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#pieChart

Comment: Would be good to add a reference to the documentation where it states this.

Comment: Looks like the documentation has now been updated, so I've added a link

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on their own Live Code feature: http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav

Answer (score 12):

There is AFAIK no option to do this, but you can select the `g` element that contains the legend manually and move it, e.g.

```
d3.select(".nv-legendWrap")
  .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lars. When I try this with a line chart and try to use the dots in the legend to turn on / off the lines, the legend returns to it's original position. Adding the same code to it's "onclick" behavior also produces erratic results. Any further suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to make sure that you "undo" any of these modifications (or modify the NVD3 source).

Comment: @user3898336 answer does not have the issue mentioned by Tariq Khokhar

Answer (score 6):

You can permanently change the position of the legend for an nvd3 chart model by editing the JS file itself.  This may work better for chart refreshing than including the positioning in your initialization.  Search the JS (like multiBarChart.js or lineChart.js) for:
 `g.select('.nv-legendWrap')`.
 An `.attr` will be defined just after that, replace that with:

```
.attr('transform', 'translate(10,270)')
```

Where 10 is the x value the legend is shifted and 270 is the y value it is shifted.

Comment: I;m facing the same issue, but i tried what Brian Hogan suggested, unfortunately it doesnt work.i tried in the nvd3.js files as well..no change at all..

Comment: Sorry to hear that user1234.  If you post a link to a jsfiddle, codepen, or another question on stackoverflow the community maybe able to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to solve the same issue with a lineChart. First I just added a

```
d3.select('.nv-legendWrap').attr('transform', 'translate(0, 475)')
```

But it reverts back to default when you resize the chart. So I also copied the line and added it inside my windowResize() function, which worked. BUT then when I click the legend to hide/show lines it moves BACK to default position.

I think the best solution might be to edit the js file.

It seems like when it comes to charting there's just no easy solution. NVD3.js documentation is very lacking and limited. But D3.js is huge and also complicated...you just can't have both ease and customization, you have to give up one or the other.

**Update:**
If you just need to move it a little you can simply do the following:

```
chart.legend.margin({top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust `chart.legend.margin`. It has `top`, `right`, `left`, `bottom` as attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Doc on legend is here : 
http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#legend

as an example:

```
chart.legend.rightAlign(false);
```